# Disconnecting Dojo Inline Events

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

Is it possible to disconnect an event added to a Dojo dijit using the inline method?

For example these methods on a dojox.form.Rating:

```
<span id="rating_0" dojoType="dojox.form.Rating" numStars="5" value="4">
  <script type="dojo/event" event="onMouseOver">
  oCatalogueGallery.displayRatingText( 0 )
  </script>
  <script type="dojo/event" event="onMouseOut">
  oCatalogueGallery.displayRatingText( 0 )
  </script>
  <script type="dojo/event" event="onClick">
  oCatalogueGallery.updateRating( 0, 3048, 4 )
  </script>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  In order to remove an event handler, you need a handle to it, and I don't see a way to get a handle besides getting it as the return value from connect().